# Windows 10 Files not showing up for start menu search

Tags: windows, windows-10

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10, none of my files show up during a start menu search.  All of my files are on my D drive, and Windows is installed on my C.  I have made sure my files are indexed properly.  Programs show up fine during search, it’s just files.

Comment: Does it work if you click the `My Stuff` button? [This one](http://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2015/12/my-stuff-search-windows10.jpg?itok=sUmWdlxK)

Comment: @Jonno Yes, it does work that way

Answer (score 0):

As Jonno said! It should work if you click at the `My Stuff`-button!

[image]